# Node package gh-pages bug

Tags: github-pages

I'm working on a react site based on create-react-app. I'm publishing it using gh-pages.

Problem : I have absolutely no idea why, how or what's happening, but when I deploy my app into gh-pages, my whole production is completely bugged, css files partly load, images don't show up, the styles are partly missing and partly showing up, tons of errors in the console (fixing them doesn't fix the issue), while I haven't touched a single line of code between the time `npm start` works and the time I execute `gh-pages -d build`. I'm wondering if I'm missing out something or if the gh-pages devs just abandoned the project and any hope to make it work properly.

Thank you !